# Appcelerator: Elements are not added to views in android

Tags: javascript, android, xml, titanium, appcelerator

I've been working on a multi platform mobile application. I almost finished it but I always tested on **iOS** (because of reasons). Now I am able to test on **Android** to find out that it fails in many ways.

The main problem here is that when I use:

```
alloy.createSomeElement({
    //params
})
$.someView.add(someElemet);
```

the element is not added to the view. As I mentioned, this only happens on Android and works just fine on iOS.

Here I show you an example and it's result in both platforms.

```
e.json.forEach(function(address) {
    var addressView = Ti.UI.createView({
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            width : '90%',
            layout : 'horizontal',
            touchEnabled : true,
            Address_id : address.id
        });
        var icoCont = Ti.UI.createView({
            height : 20,
            width : '10%'
        });
        var icon = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            height : '20',
            width : '20',
            image : "/compartidos/persona3.png",
            touchEnabled : false
        });
        var addressText = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            width : Ti.UI.FILL,
            left : 1,
            text : address.street + " - " + address.ext_number,
            font : {
                fontSize : 12,
                fontFamily : "Nunito-Bold",
            },
            touchEnabled : false,
            color: "#000"
        });
        if (address.alias)
            addressText.text = address.alias;
        var separator = Ti.UI.createView({
            height : 5,
            width : '100%',
            top : 5,
            bottom : 5,
            backgroundColor : '#8C000000',
            touchEnabled : false
        });
        addressView.add(icoCont, addressText);
        icoCont.add(icon);
        $.container.add(addressView, separator);
    });
```

Result on iOS: [result on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWrzw.png)

And this on Android: [result on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOhni.png)

I really hope you can help me with this.

note: Nueva dirección and Dirección actual are not generated this way, those exist in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue after a long cycle of try & error. I'm posting my solution only in case somebody faces the same problem.

Seems that in Android I can't add multiple elements in a single instruction like this

```
addressView.add(icoCont, addressText);
```

The only thing I had to do is separate it in 2 (One for each element) like so

```
addressView.add(icoCont);
addressView.add(addressText);
```

Comment: You could significantly reduce the amount of code you're writing by using Alloy databinding. By using a simple mock library and Backbone Models and collections you could replace your code with one line of JS in the controller, and simplify the XML and TSS. 

The result would be less code and you'd take advantage of all the features Alloy databinding has to offer.  

There's an [example here of a simple Todo app](https://github.com/appcdev/imagine-workshops-todo) that uses a small mock library to turn arrays into collections.

Comment: thank you, I will improve this app later, for now the deadline is very close and I have to finish asap.

Answer (score 0):

You can add many views in single add statement, but you need to pass them as array like : **addressView.add( [icoCont, addressText] );**

Comment: I just tested that and it causes the application to crash. It does not work. thank you anyway.

Comment: I had read it from Docs but perhaps docs are not updated sometimes. So it's better to add them one by one.